# Unable to Add ESXi hosts to vCenter Server

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I am using two ESXi 6.5 hosts running independently. Both are DELL servers, utilising local storage. Both are running fine. I have a vCenter licence and I have downloaded the appliance and created a vm for it on one of the ESXi hosts.

When I try to add the hosts to the vCenter's datacenter via "Add host...", it gets the credentials, dispalys the name of VMs on the Host Summary page correctly and after clicking on Finish in the Ready to complete screen, times out after some time saying **"A general system error occurred: Timed out waiting for vpxa to start"**

I have created DNS entries and PTR entries on my domain server. Time on the vCenter machine and the ESXi host are correct.

Please help...

ESXi version: 6.5.0 build number: 4564106
vSphere Web Client Version 6.0.0 Build 5112533

Comment: Can the ESXi hosts resolve your vcenter? Have you checked if the ESXi firewall is blocking the vCenter requests?

Comment: I can ping from the ESXi to the vCenter Server. In the firewall config of ESXi, I see incoming port TCP 902 listed under NFC as Enabled. Also vSphere Web Client has incoming ports TCP 443, 902 enabled.

Comment: vCenter version 6.5 or newer?  same subsets? firewalls?

Comment: All are on same subnets, connected directly. No hardware firewall in between.

Comment: vCenter Server Appliance version 6.0.0.30000

Comment: :/ Isn't that a gotcha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't manage ESXi 6.5 hosts with vCenter Server 6. You need to use vCenter Server 6.5.

http://partnerweb.vmware.com/comp_guide2/sim/interop_matrix.php?#interop&2=&1=

Comment: That was my mistake. I had some how gone to the wrong web page and downloaded the wrong ISO. Thanks people!!!